# Dynamically adding an attribute Directive to a transclude Directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm attempting to dynamically add an attribute Directive to a transclude directive.

For example, the template would start off as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

After an event takes place (eg. a click), it would then have an attribute Directive added, such as:

```
<div class="container" some-directive>
  <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

I'm using the following JavaScript to do this:

```
div = angular.element("#demoParentDirective .container").clone();
div.attr('some-directive','');
div = $compile(div)($scope);
angular.element("#demoParentDirective .container").replaceWith(div);
```

However, this results in:

```
Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. Element: <div ng-transclude="">
```

I've created a stripped down demo of what I'm trying to do in Plunker to show how I'm doing it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/xIKwJqKFbvs6DVnJrDUh?p=preview

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

## Update:

As requested, I've created a follow-up question asking if there is a better way to achieve what it is I'm trying to achieve:

[Creating a 'tab-away' attribute Directive with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024053/creating-a-tab-away-attribute-directive-with-angularjs)

Comment: Your child directive doesn't have `transclude` property. So when you replace element with that directive it has `ng-transclude` inside the clone. Really not clear what you are really trying to do. Demo is likely too strpped down ... or there maybe there's a better way to do whatever you are trying to do

Comment: Essentially I want to add a directive that can handle key presses for the element (and it's children) it's added to. It's to handle when someone tabs away from a control (eg. a collection of elements). I only want the directive to apply when something has been toggled on (hence the need to apply the directive dynamically). An ng-blur directive doesn't help here because it's when they leave one of many elements. It's kind of a modified ng-blur.

Comment: I really encourage you to ask perhaps another question about what you really are trying to accomplish. Compiling and re-compiling the DOM in order to apply one directive doesn't seem like a very good approach

Comment: Yeah, since applying it to the project itself, it is bringing about other issues. It's getting late where I am, so perhaps I'll write a slightly higher level question tomorrow. Thanks all.

Comment: That's why I didn't provide an answer...the whole process looks very flaky in demo

Comment: I've created a new question, hoping to find a better way to go about this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024053/creating-a-tab-away-attribute-directive-with-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

Adding transclude to your child directive fixes the issue in your Plunk

```
angular.module('demo')
.directive('demoChildDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      priority: 500,
      transclude: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
        console.log("Child Directive Applied.");
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: brlliant!  bet that was hard to figure out

Comment: Thank you, both. I don't know whether shivas copied you @charlietfl or not, but thank you both anyway. It seems to have done the trick.

I was hoping it was something that simple, but never actually expected it.

Comment: @charlietfl i did see your comment as soon as i posted the answer. Thanks

Comment: @greggannicott, of course it's simple. It's as simple as a bandage on a gunshot wound. You are likely doing something improperly or against best practices, thus running into these issues. That's why charlietfl commented in order to gain more insight into what you are trying to accomplish, and this answer only provided a bandage.